# Prove that k-cycles generate S_n for k even

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Prove that $k$-cycles generate $S_n$ for $k$ even, $k \leq n$.

How do I about proving this? I know I should do it by induction. The $k=2$ case is simple. I'm having trouble going from the inductive step to the $k+2$ case.

I'm thinking that I want to show something like: $k$-cycles can be expressed as a product of $k+2$-cycles. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It's actually the opposite you have to show, i.e., that a $(k+2)$-cycle can be written as the product of a $k$-cycle with some other permutation. This is easy since $$(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_{k+1},a_{k+2})=(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_k)\circ ( a_k,a_{k+1},a_{k+2})$$

Comment: So say we write $(a_1, ..., a_{k+2})$ as the product of a $k$-cycle and another smaller cycle. We don't have a recipe for writing any permutation in terms of a $k+2$-cycle still, so I don't see how it's the opposite that we have to show.

Comment: bof has shown how to do this directly, but it is easy if you know that for $n \ge 5$ the only proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$.

Answer (score 3):

We know that $S_n$ is generated by the $2$-cycles. If $k$ is even, $2\le k\le n,$ then a $2$-cycle can be expressed as a product of three $k$-cycles in the following way:
$$(1\ 2)=(1\ 3\ 2\ 4)(4\ 3\ 2\ 1)^2$$
$$(1\ 2)=(1\ 3\ 5\ 2\ 4\ 6)(6\ 5\ 4\ 3\ 2\ 1)^2$$
$$(1\ 2)=(1\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 2\ 4\ 6\ 8)(8\ 7\ 6\ 5\ 4\ 3\ 2\ 1)^2$$
and so forth.